# Show a table (number of rows variable) on a div after click button? Works until some point

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table

(This is my first question here and I am new to programming)

I am stuck on a problem and I tried to take something from here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/4pEJB/
- [Dynamically generated table - using an array to fill in TD values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407781/dynamically-generated-table-using-an-array-to-fill-in-td-values)

The function I created receive two vectors and creates a table with 2 columns, one for each vector, and lines = vector.length.
The function works fine, it seems to create the table as I need, but it doesn't show the table created on the browser screen after button click. By using some 'alert()' on the for loops I was able to verify that it uses the correct data.

In fact, when the button is clicked, it calls another function that processes some data and passes two vectors on this function I am showing here, but this part works well.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<div class="tableDiv">

  <input  type="button" onclick="createtable([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10])" value="Show data">

</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript part:

```
function createtable(vet_1,vet_2){

    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

    for (var r=0;r<vet_1.length;r++){
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var c=0;c<2;c++){
           var cell = document.createElement("td");
           if (c==0){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_1[r]));}
           else if(c==1){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_2[r]));}
        row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }
tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

When the function finishes the table feed, it stops on `tableDiv.appendChild(table);`

Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated! (I speak portuguese, I am sorry for some errors)

EDIT: it's possible to avoid the increment on the number of table rows that occurs every time we click the button (the solution provided generates one new table under the previous table). To solve this, I just added this line on the beggining of the function code (need to put the button outside the div and let the div empty, otherwise it will hide the button): 
`document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are capturing by id, but you set up a class.chang it to id

```
<div id="tableDiv">
```

and append the tableBody into table.You're populating the table body with rows, but never appended the body into the table element.

```js
function createtable(vet_1,vet_2){

    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

    for (var r=0;r<vet_1.length;r++){
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var c=0;c<2;c++){
           var cell = document.createElement("td");
           if (c==0){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_1[r]));}
           else if(c==1){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_2[r]));}
        row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    tableBody.appendChild(row);

    }
 table.appendChild(tableBody) // append tableBody into the table element
tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv">

  <input  type="button" onclick="createtable([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10])" value="Show data">

</div>
```

Comment: @guialmpin glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

You try to append the `var table` to the `tableDiv` but the `var table` is stil empty.

Before append the `tableBody` to the `var table` and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use id instead of class in your HTML Markup

```
<div id="tableDiv">
```

and then use the following code.

```
function createtable(vet_1,vet_2){

var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var r=0;r<vet_1.length;r++){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var c=0;c<2;c++){
       var cell = document.createElement("td");
       if (c==0){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_1[r]));}
       else if(c==1){cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vet_2[r]));}
    row.appendChild(cell);
    }
tableBody.appendChild(row);
}
table.appendChild(tableBody);
tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

First you are accessing the div using id whereas the node is defined with a class.
Secondly, you have to append the body to the table node first, and then append the table to the div selected.

Try this code snippet to move on.